# How to make button visible with string holding buttons name

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey I am trying to make a page where different buttons shows up when the amount in an array is bigger than 0. I was kinda hoping i could make the button name as a string, but that dosnt work. I also looked up controllers and tried to find someone with the same problem but i cant. My code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i != amount.Length; i++)
    {
        if (amount[i] > 0)
        {
            string button = "Button" + i;
            Button[i].Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

I feel like if I could make it look like the code over it would look much cleaner than:

```
        for (int i = 0; i != amount.Length; i++)
    {
        if (amount[0] > 0)
        {

            button.Visible = true;

        }




       else if (amount[1] > 0)
       {

            button.Visible = true;

        }

#And so on (goes up to whatever the amount of numbers are in the array)...
    }
```

Comment: You cannot create a button from a string. You need dynamically created controls. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

although i do not really understand your question do you mean something like that?

```
    string[] buttonNames = new string[3] {"button1", "button2", "button3" };
    for (int i = 0; i != amount.Length; i++)
    {
        if (amount[i] > 0)
        {
            Control button = this.Controls[buttonNames[i] ];
            button.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you <3

Comment: Just tried it and it says I cant convert from string to int in Control button = this.Controls[buttonNames[i]];

Comment: Just tested it and it is working, have you put the button **Name** into the buttonNames array instead of the buttonText?

Comment: Its saying that it cant convert string to int and buttonNames[i] is underlined with a red line :(